How to identify a Muslim by look?
We are to say "As-salaamu Alaikkum" ("May peace be upon you") when meeting a Muslim. But nowadays it is difficult to know who is Muslim and who is not. So my question is, can we say "salaam" to any person whom we do not know, whether he/she is Muslim or not?
If not, then how can we identify if a person is Muslim or not?

As-salaam.
Being a Muslim is a state of heart and mind.
You can't tell by the look.
Muslims and non-muslims are not distinguished by skin colour, shape of the head or nose, or language.
As for the greeting, to offer peace is a good idea.
It has had some misuse, though. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goedendag .
Allegedly the Dutch in time of war greeted everyone with "goedendag" (good day) and slew everyone with their halberds that were not quick enough to answer or having a slightly french accent.

Wa alaikkum wa salaam

If you don't know the person then you make a guess based on circumstantial indicators and whatever decision you make is fine. Initiating the greeting is not obligatory (according to the majority madhab) even if the other person is a Muslim, and initiating the greeting to a disbeliever by mistake is not a sin.
As an example of indicators: if you are in a Muslim majority place then any person you see in your locality can be assumed to be a Muslim because of probability unless you observe or know of clear evidence to the contrary.
If the Muslims and non-Muslims in a society typically have distinct apparel and appearance then you can judge based on that. For example a man having a beard or a woman wearing proper hijab could be an indicator that they are Muslim, or a person wearing a cross could be an indicator that they are not Muslim.
Some madhabs hold that if you later come to know that you have mistakenly greeted a disbeliever then it is recommended to withdraw your greeting.

مر ابن عمر بنصراني فسلم عليه، فرد عليه، فأخبر أنه نصراني، فلما علم رجع إليه فقال‏:‏ رد علي سلامي‏
Ibn 'Umar passed by a Christian who greeted him and Ibn 'Umar returned the greeting He was told that the man was a Christian. When he learned that, he went back to him and said, 'Give me back my greeting.'
— Al-Adab Al-Mufrad

